# Highest Product you can get from k of the integers

Tags: javascript, algorithm, greedy

I am working on the following problem:

> Given an arrayOfInts, find the highestProduct you can get from k of the integers.

This is the solution I have come up with so far based on a generalization of getting the highestProduct from 3 of the integers.

```
var getHighestProductOfk = function (arrayOfInts, k) {
  if (arrayOfInts.length < k) {
    throw Error('Array should be higher than k');
  }

  highestProductArray = [arrayOfInts[0]];
  lowestProductArray = [arrayOfInts[0]];

  for (let i=1; i<k; i++) {
    highestProductArray[i] = highestProductArray[i-1]*arrayOfInts[i];
    lowestProductArray[i] = lowestProductArray[i-1]*arrayOfInts[i];
  }

  for(let i=1; i<arrayOfInts; i++) {
    let currentInt = arrayOfInts[i];

    for(let j=k-1; j>=0; j--) {
      highestProductArray[j] = Math.max(
        highestProductArray[j],
        highestProductArray[j-1]*currentInt,
        lowestProductArray[j-1]*currentInt
      );

      lowestProductArray[j] = Math.min(
        lowestProductArray[j],
        lowestProductArray[j-1]*currentInt,
        highestProductArray[j-1]*currentInt
      );
    }

    // highest number
    highestProductArray[0] = Math.max(highestProductArray[0], currentInt)

    // lowest number
    lowestProductArray[0] = Math.max(lowestProductArray[0], currentInt)
  }

  return highestProductArray[k-1];
}
```

Any idea what I do wrong? 
for the following example [1, 10, -5, 1, -100], the result is -50 instead of 5000. 
lowest number is 1 and the highest is 1  instead of -100 and 10

The solution for the highestProduct of three of the integers:

```
var getHighestProductOfThree = function (arrayOfInts) {
  if (arrayOfInts.length < 3) {
    throw Error('Array should be higher than 3');
  }

  let highestProductOfThree = arrayOfInts[0]*arrayOfInts[1]*arrayOfInts[2];

  let highestProductOfTwo = arrayOfInts[0]*arrayOfInts[1];
  let lowestProductOfTwo = arrayOfInts[0]*arrayOfInts[1];

  let highest = arrayOfInts[0];
  let lowest = arrayOfInts[0];

  for (let i=1; i<arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
    let currentInt = arrayOfInts[i];

    highestProductOfThree = Math.max(
      highestProductOfThree,
      highestProductOfTwo*currentInt,
      lowestProductOfTwo*currentInt
    );

    highestProductOfTwo = Math.max(
      highestProductOfTwo,
      currentInt*highest,
      currentInt*lowest
    );

    lowestProductOfTwo = Math.min(
      lowestProductOfTwo,
      currentInt*lowest,
      currentInt*highest
    );

    highest = Math.max(
      highest,
      currentInt
    );

    lowest = Math.min(
      lowest,
      currentInt
    );

  }

  return highestProductOfThree;
}
```

Comment: I think you should initialize both arrays with the first number only (otherwise you would have to adapt the loop because `highestProductArray[2]` is only valid from location 2 on etc). Furthermore, accessing `highestProductArray[j-1]` is invalid for `j=0`.

Comment: i think, you can sort the items, get groups of two at both ends of the array and check. if greater, take them and proceed.

Comment: @NinaScholz Began writing a solution to do this, turns out (unless I'm missing a trick) it is much more complex than it first appears; what happens if you need to take more numbers than you have positive numbers? You need to track which ones were from the double negatives. What happens if you're forced to take an odd number of negative numbers? You actually want all the numbers closest to zero.

Comment: It may be easier to calculate the product of the whole array, if it's negative, remove the smallest negative, if it's positive, remove either the smallest positive or the two smallest negatives, repeat until you have `k` numbers remaining. If it's still negative, swap smallest positive for lowest leftover negative. In the case where you are required to take an odd number of negatives, try to catch this early on and just choose the closest to zero for everything

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea. Sort the numbers. Next, pick from the largest positive numbers as many as you can, up to `k` of them. Now pick the largest even group from the smallest negative numbers that form a larger product than the  smallest positive numbers, which we will replace with them. (There are some edge cases, such as only one negative and `k - 1` positives).

```
Pick 3 from [1, 10, -5, 1, -100]

Sort => [-100,-5,1,1,10]

Pick largest positives => 10 * 1 * 1

Pick largest even number of smallest negatives we can,
whose product is greater than the one replaced

  => (-100) * (-5) > 1 * 1

Answer => 10 * (-100) * (-5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my preliminary thoughts, I suggest to sort the values ascending, take the highest value, if the count is odd and use the rest with pairs.

This keeps a positive product with a loop until all needed factors are used.

In a while loop with a check for count, the pairs are chosen, if the product is greate than of the beginning of the array. This includes negative numbers, but works for only positive or negative numbers as well.

```js
function getHighestProductOfK(a, k) {
    var p = 1;

    a.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
    if (k > a.length || k & 2 && a[a.length - 1] < 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (k % 2) {
        p = a.pop();
        k--;
    }
    while (k) {
        p *= a[0] * a[1] > a[a.length - 2] * a[a.length - 1] ? a.shift() * a.shift() : a.pop() * a.pop();
        k -= 2;
    }
    return p;
}

console.log(getHighestProductOfK([1, 10, -5, 1, -100], 3));
console.log(getHighestProductOfK([3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3));
console.log(getHighestProductOfK([-3, -4, -5, -6, -7], 3));
console.log(getHighestProductOfK([3, 4, -5, -6, -7], 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Needs some testing to make sure it always gives good answers..

```
function largestProduct(k, arr) {
    if (k > arr.length) throw new RangeError('Not enough numbers');

    let pos = [],
        neg = [];
    arr.forEach(e => {
        if (e >= 0) pos.push(e);
        else neg.push(e);
    });
    pos.sort((a, b) => a < b); //  9,  8,  7, ...
    neg.sort((a, b) => a > b); // -9, -8, -7, ...

    if (pos.length === 0 && k % 2) // k requires odd number of negatives
        return neg.slice(-k); // give the smallest number TODO: same return

    let big = [];
    while (k > 1) grow();
    if (k === 1) { // we've reached the end of doubles but still need more
        if (pos.length) big.push(pos[0]);
        else { // ran out of positives, backtrack
            big = big.slice(0, -1);
            big.push(neg[0], neg[1]);
        }
    }

    return {
        factors: big,
        product: big.reduce((a, b) => a * b, 1)
    };

    function grow() { // choose the next best number
        let doublepos = pos[0] * pos[1],
            doubleneg = neg[0] * neg[1];
        if (doublepos > doubleneg || doubleneg !== doubleneg) {
            big.push(pos[0]);
            pos = pos.slice(1);
            k -= 1;
        } else {
            big.push(neg[0], neg[1]);
            neg = neg.slice(2);
            k -= 2;
        }
    }
}
```